# Starting a video session with webRTC.io works inconsistently

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I'm using [webRTC.io](https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io) to create a video chat between two browsers. My experience, with different sequence of events, the session will sometimes start successfully and sometime will not.

Even when running their [demo](https://github.com/webRTC/webrtc.io-demo) as is, I get the same experience. I'm not sure if the browser banner asking me to allow the use of the camera and microphone is affecting the correct sequence of events.

I could start two browsers once and have a two way video working perfectly. Then create a new room (again with their [demo](https://github.com/webRTC/webrtc.io-demo)) and fail to connect. Then, sometimes, after refreshing the page on one of the sides, the session will start again.

Comment: sounds like a bug in webRTC.io...

Comment: @BenjaminTrent I'm trying webRTC.io because it seemed simple and stable. What other library is similar and more current?

Comment: I would say this one is as good as any(all are rather young still). Probably working with it and the creators on Github would be your best bet. What are the specific steps that occur when you run into the error? I had what seems to be similar issue in my personal implementation and had to quickly recreate the peerconnection when ever parties left the room(I do not use webrtc.io)